# Powering two 5v devices from rechargeable batteries

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, low-power

I am taking an old rotary phone (similar to [this](https://boomertechtalk.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/800px-Rotaryphone1.jpg)), then adding two modern devices, to make it run as a VOIP phone.

The first device is a Grandstream HT801 ATA which per its spec sheet ships with a Output 5.0VDC/1.0A power supply.  The other item is an iogear Universal Wi-Fi N Transmitter- Ethernet to Wi-Fi N adapter, which per it's spec sheets requires 5.0VDC/500ma power supply.

Ideally, I would like to add a little battery pack that would be rechargeable and power both of these devices for 10 minutes so I could have everything wireless.  I have no idea how to work out the electrical engineering aspect of this so would love any guidance you can offer on the easiest way to accomplish this. Also, need to find a small battery pack, or at least flat, since there isn't much room left once the two devices are installed.

Comment: What is your definition of "little"?

Comment: The antique phone was powered from 48VDC. It will be silent when powered from only 5V because its microphone and earphone are over 100 years old.

Answer (score 2):

1. Buy a 5 V power bank
2. Use it to power your devices
3. Done

Comment: I thought of this, but didn't know if I could accomplish the same things with a little battery pack of some sort.  The power bank size isn't as flexible as adding some batteries and cables, if that is an option.

Comment: You could, but **much** more effort and with lower safety. Be smart and safe: buy a ready-made solution.